# Save the input data until user get changed

Tags: java

I would like to know how to store the give input data and perform the calculations even after re-opening the program.

I am developing a college library management system, i would like know how to change the fine amount and store it for each day calculations by the ADMINISTRATOR and save this amount until he changes it again. Waiting for someones help.

Thank You.

Comment: are you using a database already?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a data base, write the given input to a XML file while closing the program like:

```
closeProgram(){
writeToXml();
exit();
}
then  write a method for your programs startup or maybe in main method:
startup(){

readFromXml();
storeXmlToDataStructure();

//and use  recovered data from xml to continue calculation


}
```

but if you can use database ,it is the best way to keep your data for a collage library management system.